# Javascript get last modification of a web page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, last-modified

I am trying to create a javascript function which returns the last modified date of a remote url which it recieves. I have tried many different methods, none of which seem to work. The following code seems like it may be close, but unfortunately doesnt work.

```
function getlastmod(url) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", url, false);
    req.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified");
    req.send("");
    return req.responseText;
}
```

The function will be used in a chrome extension that I am making.
Thanks for any help-Josh

Comment: If the server doesn't tell you the `Last-Modified`, it is fundamentally impossible for you to find it.

Comment: @sLaks This code should indeed work, make an answer

Comment: @Esailija if the server tells the last-modified

Comment: @rsplak it doesn't matter if it tells it because the code ignores it. It is also trying to get the header before the request has even been made.

Comment: I withdrew my answer as all you are receiving is the header, which I think would work cross domain; however, as SLaks said, the server has to give you the last-modified time.  If the server does not, it defaults to the current time (GMT).

Comment: @vol7ron It won't work cross-domain if the full request doesn't work cross-domain. I have already given you plenty of references on this. Cross-domain xhr can be done just as  well as same-domain xhr can be done. ,http://jsfiddle.net/7qA7R/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some issues:

- You are trying to get the headers before a connection has even been made. You can only read the headers after the server has responded.
- You are not doing anything with the result

Try this:

```
function getlastmod(url, cb) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", url);
    req.send(null);
    req.addEventListener("load", function() {
        cb(req.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified"));
    }, false);
}

getlastmod("/", function(v) {
    console.log(v); //"Wed, 01 Aug 2012 14:13:22 GMT"
});
```

This requires your extension to ask for the [right permissions](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html) (because you are doing cross-origin xhr) as well as the server to send the header.

Comment: Please take this conversation to chat. Comments are not meant for real time collaboration.